# Are Boltzmann brains really possible?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

My question is the following: can particles luckily aggregate
and instantaneously generate a full adult body? In general,
can a full body appear from "nowhere" (meaning not following
the canonical biological development from a single cell), for instance right in front
of me?

When people talk about Boltzmann brains
they usually assume that this is the case, but what is the
physical ground for such a scenario? Is it a real possibility
(independently of how unlikely that would be) compatible with
the laws of physics (if so, which), or is it possible in a merely loose sense
of the word?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: [See section 6 on page 18 of this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208013).

Comment: You've got the problem wrong.  It's not whether a biological object can appear in intergalactic space.  The problem is, how do we know WHETHER the idealized CONTENTS of the "brain" (memories, imaginings, thoughts, sensations, etc.) are REALLY the result of our interactions with ANY environment OUTSIDE of our minds.  It's MUCH more likely that the electromagnetic constellation that could account for those feelings appeared spontaneously through quantum fluctuations in some tiny part of spacetime, as their volume and duration could be MUCH smaller than the dimensions imagined for the universe.

Comment: I've got to add that, accepting the sociable view, OF COURSE biological objects CAN appear in intergalactic space:  In that view, we ARE biological objects, and the galaxy we inhabit IS BETWEEN other galaxies!

Answer (score 4):

The number for the probability is hugely small. Not at all like the previous answers. The only way the argument make any possible sense if you you consider an infinite universe, with an infinite number of particles, or an essentially infinity of multiverses. You multiply infinite by the small probability and yes you can get Boltzmann brains. You can also get probably about the same number of demons who go about destroying them. Everything can happen in eternity.

Consider the possibilities. Treat the case of the brain having $10^{26}$ particles that are the ones that define the possibles states, as in @Koo's answer. We'll see that his calculations are way off. In reality it's a lot more, but let's still stick with that number.

If you had 2 particles with 6 possible microstates each you'd get $6^2$ possibilities. The possible positions of one particle is not 3, but 3 dimensions multiplied by the number of possible positions in one dimension, say 1 position every 1 angstrom in the brain. That roughly gives you $10^9$ positions. Momentum in each dimension say is another $10^9$. Total possible states is $(10^9)^6$ = $10^{54}$ possible single particle states. With the number of atoms or molecules stated, the number of possible combinations is (number of states) raised to the number of particles, or roughly $(10^{54})^{10^{26}}$.

That is roughly a probability of ONE in $(10^{10})^{26}$ particles that will maybe form a Boltzmann brain. That is ONE in $10^{260}$. In actual fact the number is probably less because multiple particles could do what we said one particle does, so there is some interchange of particles where the end result is essentially the same Boltzmann brain. So figure that out, with permutations, let's say reduce the number by $10^{26}$. That still ONE in $10^{234}$.

The only way it works is if the universe of particle, or the multiverse, is so huge as to be infinite. It does not work for our observable universe of about $10^{80}$ particles. You'd need about $10^{154}$ of our visible universes to get one Boltzmann brain.

Maybe I'm off some, but if you do it exactly assuming random works, our visible universe is not enough to come out with one.

Comment: Good catch, I forgot to constrain the volume to within a human brain. Actually thinking about it again, momentum doesn't affect the macrostate of being a brain, so it's $(10^9)^3$ possible microstates per atom. Besides, surely this analysis applies to a snapshot of the Universe at a certain time, so don't we need to consider probabilities over the entire lifetime of the Universe?

Comment: Separate positions: particles can be anywhere, every one where is a different position state. Similarly with momentum. But since I got $10^{54}$ and then approximated that as just 10 it makes no difference. It's the number of particles in the exponent that dominates it. As for times: yes, that would increase it, say a universe last 10 billion years when the conditions for brain forming are possible (it's probably less), MORE

Comment: let's say every second they can rearrange with some stay there stability (chemical-biological reactions take some time), there's $10^7$ secs in a year, so that's $10^{17}$ seconds in the universe.  So instead the probability  becomes one in $10^{137}$. Still a ridiculously small number.                There are reasons why it took evolution a few billion years to evolve a brain, and it was not random reactions, except initially for simple biochemicals. Then it was evolution, slow but sure.

Comment: So why bother with Boltzmann brains when we have real ones? More interesting is to figure out other architectures besides carbon, hydrogen and oxygen. otherwise look for earth like planets like they are doing.

Comment: Thank you. My question is not about how unlikely the appearance of a boltzmann brain would be; I just want to know whether or not it can appear, in principle. Your calculations assume that any single configuration whatsoever can istantaneously arise from fluctuations, the probability being then given by seeing how specific that configuration is with respect to all the possible combinations. But the premise is precisely what I would to have rigorous justification for: how do we know that every possible state can istantaneously arise from the disordered one?

Comment: @Michele O. So that's a reasonable question, and there's two ways to look at it, I think. One is to try to try to figure how whether you can assume that there is a lot of randomness in the universe, or if not calculate for how long or under what conditions that randomness can occur. Then you calculate limiting it to those circumstances. The other one is to make some also reasonable assumptions. That randomness ocurs enough, and figure it out by assuming the enough is good enough since we're doing things so approximately and errors of factor of say ten billion don't really matter. CONTINUED

Comment: At least if you have an infinity or very large number of universes or multiverses. Since the premise of random brains is so hypothetical anyway, I doubt anybody has bothered to do much more that the simplest of estimates. Something similar was happening when there were discussions of how likely life is in this universe. Not too long ago (30 years?) somebody came up with a reasonable formula where you can start putting in factors, real or hypothetical, and now astrobiology is sort of a science. But mostly physicists will stick with the simplest way unless there's a good reason.

Comment: By the way, it is thought, if I remember right, that the first organic molecules arose from random encounters in water ponds and watery areas where the molecules would just move around due to random or just standard water motion. Do t know if it's been calculated, I'd guess so because it's one (good?) hypothesis. I think, myself, because molecules and atoms have a huge tendency to react with each other, otherwise to me it would seem unbelievable.

Comment: @Bob Bee Would an infinite probability (for or against any possibility) not be most concisely expressed (using less ink in our printers) as a number raised to the power of an infinite number of digits?  I think your entire argument's making more of a case for an infinite divisibility of space and time than it's making for any total impossibility of what has plainly actually happened, on billions of occasions within the earth alone (to judge by the number of brains its atmosphere appears to contain, per that reading of population statistics which my brain--Boltzmann or otherwise--has absorbed).

Comment: The key weakness, I think, is in your use of the word "observable" (although I believe the eyes are, biologically, sometimes considered to be extensions of the brain).  The actual universe might well be observable only in the sense that it would be repetitious (which seems plausible, but lacking in proof).

Answer (score 1):

Boltzmann brains do not require entire bodies to be formed, because all our experiences and memories can be translated to some state of the brain (similar idea to [brain in a vat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat)).

I'm not considering subatomic particles, nor different electron energy levels, and limiting myself to human brains instead of any possible consciousness, but the core argument of probability should still hold.

There are $10^{26}$ atoms in the human brain, but $10^{79}$ atoms in the observable universe.

There is a very low probability of $10^{26}$ atoms taking on a specific structure as the brain. From [statistical mechanics,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_(statistical_mechanics)#The_microstate_in_phase_space) given a macrostate of $10^{26}$ atoms with total energy $E$, these atoms can be in any combination of microstates such that the total energy is still $E$.

Each microstate of a single atom is a 3-dimensional position vector. Assume the atom can take 1 of $10^9$ discrete positions per dimension within the cubic brain of side length $0.1m$. To require that these atoms have the one specific arrangement of a human brain would require specifying the values of all $((10^9)^3)^{10^{26}}$ microstates. The probability of which is just $1/(all\space possible\space states)$.

[possibility of Boltzmann brains existing in our observable universe redacted after discussion with Bob]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can take a brain and burn it to ash in a cramatory oven, or even gassify it if the temperature is above the carbon evaporation temperature. Now, run the movie in reverse, you have a way to make a brain from gas. It only requires the correct initial velocities 
and positions of all particles and radiation.

Comment: thank you, I had thought of this too, and this is true in classical mechanics which is time-reversible; but does the same argument work by modeling the constituents of the brain as quantum particles, or whatever is fundamental out there?

Comment: That is a good point. I am sure it works in the decoherence/MWI interpretation in which the evolution of the wavefunction is always unitary never collapses. Also, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59604/does-quantum-reversibility-require-many-worlds

Comment: The filmed way to make a brain from gas would be using two spatial dimensions to represent three of them, but maybe the complete picture could be captured in a hologram.  However, re "whatever's fundamental out there", it might not be  observable on the smallest scales that could be magnified to visibility, even with use of all the energy in our currently-observable region, or with use of energy whose mass equivalence might collapse it into a black hole.  In physics as in other fields, fundamentalism's a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Boltzmann brains typically arise in any theory that attempts to explain the low entropy initial conditions of our universe in terms of a more generic initial state that would have existed earlier. The problem is then caused by the fact that around the time of the Big Bang, the entropy achieved a local minimum after which the entropy increased. Then, as observed by Boltzmann himself, you can  increase the probability of ending up with an observer, by decreasing the size of the part of the universe that has this local minimum in the entropy. The maximum probability is obtained for the smallest size possible where you could just render the observer you're aiming for.

This is then a paradox, because a Boltzmann brain would most likely be aware of random information which is not similar to what we are aware of. This seems to rule out any theory where in the past the entropy of the universe could have been large. It also poses a problem for theories where the universe will continue to exist indefinitely, because then we could arise in the far future after the heath death of the universe as Boltzmann brains, the question is then why we find ourselves living now and not later as Boltzmann brains.